# Como añadir N cantidad de comillas simples en un conjunto de datos separado por comas dependiendo del tipo de dato usando C#

Tags: c#, lista, string, stored-procedure

Necesito agregar ese conjunto como parámetro de un procedimiento almacenado.

Tengo este código:

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    // Datos desde el formulario
    int codigo = 1;
    string Descripcion = "DescripciónN";
    int Orden = 1;
    DateTime FecMod = DateTime.Now;
    var Date = FecMod.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  // Obtener solo la fecha
    int idUsuario = 1;

    // Conjunto
    List<string> Campos = new List<string>();
    Campos.Add(codigo.ToString());
    Campos.Add(Descripcion);
    Campos.Add(Date);
    Campos.Add(Orden.ToString());
    Campos.Add(idUsuario.ToString());
    
    var VP_Datos = string.Join(",", Campos.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));

    Console.WriteLine(VP_Datos); // '1','DescripciónN','2022-02-21','1','1'
  }
}
```

**Salida requerida:** @VP_Datos = " ''1'',''DescripcionE'',''2022-01-12'',17,1 "

*En el tipo DateTime y String ocupo doble comillas simples.*

Comment: Y cual es el problema

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes hacer lo siguiente:**

1. Iteras la lista de datos string.
2. Validas que si el tipo de dato de ese campo es string o DateTime entonces lo ingresa con doble comilla simples.

**Nota:** Daria lo mismo si no validas, ya que la lista es de un solo tipo de datos que es "string", entonces no es necesaria la validación.

```
// Datos desde el formulario
int codigo = 1;
string Descripcion = "DescripciónN";
int Orden = 1;
DateTime FecMod = DateTime.Now;
var Date = FecMod.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  // Obtener solo la fecha
int idUsuario = 1;

// Conjunto
List<string> Campos = new List<string>();
Campos.Add(codigo.ToString());
Campos.Add(Descripcion);
Campos.Add(Date);
Campos.Add(Orden.ToString());
Campos.Add(idUsuario.ToString());

string vp_datos = "'' ";
foreach (var x in Campos)
{
    if (x.GetType() == Type.GetType("System.String") || x.GetType() == Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        vp_datos += $"''{x}'',";
    else
        vp_datos += $"{x}"+",";
}
vp_datos = vp_datos.Remove(vp_datos.Length - 1);
vp_datos += " ''";

Console.WriteLine(vp_datos); // '' ''1'',''DescripciónN'',''2022-02-21'',''1'',''1'' ''
```

**Sin validación ya que la lista es de tipo string:**

```
string vp_datos = "'' ";
foreach (var x in Campos)
    vp_datos += $"''{x}'',";

vp_datos = vp_datos.Remove(vp_datos.Length - 1);
vp_datos += " ''";

Console.WriteLine(vp_datos); // '' ''1'',''DescripciónN'',''2022-02-21'',''1'',''1'' ''
```

Comment: Gracias por la atención y el tiempo, si me sirvió.

Comment: Un placer, si te sirvió, por favor califícala como una respuesta útil.